# Import data from text file include numbers and strings Into Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file which has 5 columns Like this :

```
1|24|M|technician|85711
2|53|F|other|94043
3|23|M|writer|32067
4|24|M|technician|43537
5|33|F|other|15213
6|42|M|executive|98101
.
.
.
```

how can I import this fields into an array in MATLAB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) function

---

```
fid = fopen('yourfile.txt','r');                       %// open file for reading
M   = textscan(fid, '%d%d%c%s%d' , 'Delimiter','|' ) ; %// import the content into cell array
fclose(fid);                                           %// close file
```

---

This will import your data into one single [cell array](http://umathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) named `M`.
You can then keep it as it is or extract numbers and/or text strings out of it if necessary.

For different import format, set the [`format specifier`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec) option accordingly.

Comment: my text File has 943 records , but your code extract only 74 record lines.

Comment: .Also how can i extract data stored in M into a matrix?

Comment: @armanyazdanshenas, check the line 75 in the source file, there must be some characters which do not respect the format of the other lines. Also look at the `'EmptyValue'` and `'TreatAsEmpty'` options of `textscan`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you just need to use Matlab import wizard. Click `File -> Import Data...`. Then, if you want different format of data select column and convert it to specified format.
You can find converting methods here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html
[image]

Comment: How can i Store fields into an array or Matrix??

Comment: If you use wizard as in the picture (and click next) all fields will be stored in cell array.

Comment: i use import wizard but do not separate fields with '|' character and put all of  '1|24|M|technician|85711' to one cell .

Comment: You need to use "textdata" option. I use R2011 version of Matlab and it works fine.